# php round 2e decimal to 0 or 5

Tags: php

i want to round $t 2e decimal to 0 or 5.

```
 if $t= 1.31; //round to 1.30
 if $t= 1.32  //round to 1.30
 if $t= 1.33; //round to 1.35
 if $t= 1.34; //round to 1.35
 if $t= 1.36; //round to 1.35
 if $t= 1.37  //round to 1.35
 if $t= 1.38; //round to 1.40
 if $t= 1.39; //round to 1.40
```

Comment: and what have you *tried* so far?

Comment: $t = round($t*10) /10;

Comment: number_format($t,2);

Comment: please don't post information to your question as comment, but **edit** your question instead. and don't just fling code-lines at us, try some actual sentences, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this one check the [demo](https://eval.in/684637)

0.05 * round($t * 20)

```
<?php
  $ts= [1.31, 1.32, 1.33, 1.34, 1.35, 1.36, 1.37, 1.38, 1.39, 1.40];
  array_walk($ts, function($t){echo number_format($t, 2)."\t".number_format(0.05*round($t*20), 2)."\n";});
```

output,

```
  1.31  1.30
1.32    1.30
1.33    1.35
1.34    1.35
1.35    1.35
1.36    1.35
1.37    1.35
1.38    1.40
1.39    1.40
1.40    1.40
```

Answer (score 1):

You can double the value so you can round to 1 decimal, then simple divide it by 2 again

```
$t = round(($t*2), 1) / 2;
```