# PHP Rouding 44947 to 44900

Tags: php, rounding

I would like to round the the lowest digit of this integer examples:

```
1940   > 1900
104942 > 104900
44947  > 44900
```

I was trying using :

```
round( 44947, -1 )    >   44950
round( 44945, -2 )    >   45000
```

Any ideas?

Comment: elaborate *the lowest digit*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: show a number to 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483540/php-show-a-number-to-2-decimal-places)

Comment: What PHP version are you using? `round(44947, -2)` most definitely returns 44900.

Comment: You are not doing `round(round(44947,-1),-2) are you?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen No, I tried round(44947, -2) and it returns 45000. round(44947, -1) returns 44950.

Comment: [round to hundred , thousand and so on](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43932648/6521116)

Comment: [php round 2e decimal to 0 or 5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40783574/6521116)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php round 2e decimal to 0 or 5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40783574/6521116)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `floor`

```
echo floor(1940/100)*100;
```

Round will round it - so .6 becomes 1, floor rounds off, so .6 becomes 0.
So...

```
echo floor(1960/100)*100;
echo round(1960,-2);
```

will give `1900` and `2000`

Unfortunately you can't use the same thing as round and specify a number of DP's, so the /100*100 does that job.

Answer (score 0):

You have to round up to two digits to get the desired result, check this

```
$var=44947;
echo round($var,-2);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can round up to any number.in this code as you mention round to floor up to range of 100

```
$num=44947;
$num=floor($num/100)*100;
var_dump($num);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 round( 104942 , -2 , PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

> **mode** Use one of the following constants to specify the mode in which rounding occurs.

Answer (score -2):

Wouldn't round(x/100)*100 do the trick?