# Make decimal value decrease or increase

Tags: php

I have a questions to decrease or increase decimal value in my PHP. For example I have **2573000.00** I want to make it **2500000.00**. I have tried to use `round()` but not give me best answer. How to do that ?

Thank you.

Comment: [Round to max thousand, hundred etc in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43932669/6521116)

Comment: [php round 2e decimal to 0 or 5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40783574/6521116)

Comment: You will need to give more explanation, it's not at all clear what you want. Do you always want to floor the value starting at the 6th decimal to the left of the decimal? When do you want to increase?

Comment: @KrisRoofe If I use that reference I will got **2580000** not **2500000**

Comment: @Antonio Perhaps if you actually explain your question you can get better answers. We can certainly give you an answer that will convert `2573000.00` to `2500000.00`, but you never stated what functionality you are looking for. If you want to only **decrease** then don't mention **increase**.

Comment: This is done I've got the answer below. @SpencerWieczorek

Comment: @Antonio That doesn't change the fact that this question is unclear, you never stated what functionality you are looking for. It's great you got what your looking for, but future visitors won't understand your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$a = 2573000.00;
$b = (int)($a / 100000) * 100000;
echo $b;
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I'm looking for. It's works.